# reactjs - access previous element from created data function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to generate some data:

```
function createData(stock, purchase, percentdown) {
    const dataarray=[]
    for(let i = 1; i < 59; i++) {
      const startdate = new Date()
      const enddate = new Date(startdate.setMonth(startdate.getMonth(), 1))
      const date = new Date(startdate.getTime() + Math.random() * (enddate.getTime() - startdate.getTime()))
    const dateFormat = date.getMonth() + 1 + '/' + date.getDate() + '/' + date.getFullYear()
    // not getting the right dates from the above


    // If its the second element being created, other than initial I want to use the last generated stockprice
    const stockprice = stock * Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
    const percent = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)
    const percentDiff = (stockprice*percent)/100
    const purchaseprice = parseInt(stockprice) -  percentDiff
    const message =  MessageFilter(purchaseprice, stock, percent)
      dataarray.push(
       {
      id:i,
      date:dateFormat,
      stock_price:stockprice,
      purchase_price:purchaseprice,
      message:message
       }
      )
    }
    return dataarray
  }
```

What I want to get as output:

```
//Using example dates and id's
[
     {
      id:1,
      date:11/06/2022,
      stock_price: 12000,
      purchase_price: 11400,
      message:message
       },
     {
      id:2,
      date:11/07/2022,  //date increased by 1 day
      stock_price: 12600,  //price increased from last stock_price,id:1, by a random percentage
      purchase_price: 11400, //calculated using this stock price
      message:message
       }
     {
      id:3,
      date:11/07/2022,  //date increased by 1 day
      stock_price: 12300,  //price increased/decreased from last stock_price,id:2, by a random percentage
      purchase_price: 11400, //calculated using this stock price
      message:message
       }
]
```

How do I access the previous generated stockprice?

Edit:

Parameters which need to be passed to the function to get the desired output:

1- stock i.e. stockprice from a form denoted by stock in the function for 1st calculation, after which the created stockprice will be used.

2- date - not required to be passed in as it will be todays date.

3- percentdown - required for calculation of purchaseprice

4- Initial purchase price denoted by purchase for 1st element and subsequent calculation will be done by purchaseprice generated in fucntion.

Edit 2:

```
if (i === 1) {
        const stockprice = stock * Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
      } else {
        const { stock } = dataarray[dataarray.length - 1];
        const stockprice = stock * Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
      }
```

It gives me a stockprice is not defined error.

Comment: Please indicate which are the parameters that have to be passed to the function to obtain that output.

Comment: @FrancoA.Torres I think I have added all clarification on this point. Please let me know if I need to add more. I know how to do this in python but very new to Javascript and react.

Answer (score 1):

To access the last element of an array just use `arr[arr.length - 1]`. In this case, it would be:

```
const { stock_price } = dataarray[dataarray.length - 1]
```

Note: `{...}` is for destructuring, in order to extract the property `stock_price` of the object returned by the above expression.

Comment: Thanks, I am getting a stockprice is not defined error if I use an if condition. Edited question.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. There is no `stock` property in any of the elements of the `dataarray` array. So that's why `not defined error`. Instead, you should use `stock_price`, as shown in the example in the answer.